# Created Stream Does not Populate Event from the Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

I am trying to do a simple stream POC to show a stream can extract event from a topic. But the stream does not populate any data at all.
My steps:

1. Manually create a topic in Control Center console, name it `my_topic` with all default.
2. Go to the schema section, add a simple schema like below:

```js
  "connect.name": "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas.KsqlDataSourceSchema",
  "name": "KsqlDataSourceSchema",
  "namespace": "io.confluent.ksql.avro_schemas",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "ORDER_KEY",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "RETRY_REDIRECT_FLAG",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "REVISION_NUMBER",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "REDIRECT_LOCK",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "int"
      ]
    },
    {
      "default": null,
      "name": "ORDER_PAYLOAD",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Go to ksqlDB in Control Center console. And run a simple create stream statement:

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_stream
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_topic', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO');
```

4. Review all the added resources and they seem look OK.
5. Now, I am trying to publish a event to the topic and hope it is shown in the stream.

- I open another window to watch the Stream by a Ksql statement and let the statement waiting for a event coming.

```
select * from my_stream emit changes;
```

- I go the the topic's messages view in Control Center console.
- I produce a simple event like below:

```js
{"order_key":"1234-ABC-1002003001","retry_redirect_flag":"RETRY","revision_number":"000","redirect_lock":1,"order_payload":"buy fund-a 3000 shares"}
```

- in the stream event window, I don't see anything.

---

I also followed the Confluent's start guide. Did the same test for the `pageviews` topic and the stream. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/platform-quickstart.html#create-the-pageviews-topic
The weird thing that I observed is: if the datagen connector is setup and generate data feed to the topic, the stream shows them. If I disable the datagen and produce event by my self, the stream doesn't show it.

---

Anyone has the same problem resolved?

Comment: 1) You need to [`SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/troubleshoot-ksqldb/#verify-that-new-records-are-arriving-at-the-source-topic) if you want to see existing topic data. 2) Capitalization matters in Avro. Fields don't need to be upper-cased, but your produced records do need to match. Try again with both, and review other topics on that troubleshooting page, such as checking the server logs for deserialization errors that would happen with (2)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I finally find out the reason. It's an awkward reason. The confluent web console cannot publish valid AVRO. I found that the ksqlDB throw errors in serialization and complaining about magic bytes. I write a Java app to send AVRO and it works now.

Comment: Yeah, I dont use use the UI ever, for various reasons like that. Feel free to post your solution below